# Creating VNC session on specific port fails even though the port is clear

Tags: centos, tcp, vnc

Sorry in advance for the huge amount of command output text, I thought it would be more clear than paraphrasing myself.

I am using CentOS 7 and tigervnc:

```
(base) [carlos@pulsar .vnc]$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)
(base) [carlos@pulsar .vnc]$ yum list installed | grep tigervnc
Skipping unreadable repository '/etc/yum.repos.d/github_git-lfs.repo'
Skipping unreadable repository '/etc/yum.repos.d/perforce.repo'
Repodata is over 2 weeks old. Install yum-cron? Or run: yum makecache fast
tigervnc.x86_64                       1.8.0-17.el7               @base          
tigervnc-icons.noarch                 1.8.0-17.el7               @base          
tigervnc-license.noarch               1.8.0-17.el7               @base          
tigervnc-server.x86_64                1.8.0-17.el7               @base          
tigervnc-server-minimal.x86_64        1.8.0-17.el7               @base
```

When trying to start a vnc session on display :16 (corresponding to port 5916), I get this error,

```
 (base) [carlos@pulsar ~]$ vncserver :16
A VNC server is already running as :16

New 'pulsar:20 (carlos)' desktop is pulsar:20

Starting applications specified in /home/carlos/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/carlos/.vnc/pulsar:20.log
(base) [carlos@pulsar ~]$ vncserver -list

TigerVNC server sessions:

X DISPLAY # PROCESS ID
:17     22581
:20     222978
```

which I'm used to seeing, so I start looking for the culprit.

Check if there are any locks: No

```
(base) [carlos@pulsar ~]$ ls -l  /tmp/.X*
-r--r--r--. 1 carlos phoelex   11 Mar 16 19:17 /tmp/.X20-lock
-r--r--r--. 1 bindu  phoelex   11 Mar 16 14:05 /tmp/.X28-lock

/tmp/.X11-unix:
total 0
srwxrwxrwx. 1 amir     phoelex 0 Nov 18 13:35 X1
srwxrwxrwx. 1 stuart   phoelex 0 Nov 18 13:35 X10
srwxrwxrwx. 1 ranga    phoelex 0 Nov 18 13:35 X11
srwxrwxrwx. 1 scott    phoelex 0 Dec 18 13:49 X13
srwxrwxrwx. 1 pablo    phoelex 0 Nov 18 15:05 X14
srwxrwxrwx. 1 zak      phoelex 0 Nov 18 13:35 X15
srwxrwxrwx. 1 carlos   phoelex 0 Nov 18 13:35 X17
srwxrwxrwx. 1 marco    phoelex 0 Nov 18 13:35 X18
srwxrwxrwx. 1 michal   phoelex 0 Nov 18 13:35 X19
srwxrwxrwx. 1 greg     greg    0 Nov 18 13:35 X2
srwxrwxrwx. 1 carlos   phoelex 0 Mar 16 19:17 X20
srwxrwxrwx. 1 candido  phoelex 0 Nov 18 14:11 X23
srwxrwxrwx. 1 mihai    phoelex 0 Nov 18 14:00 X25
srwxrwxrwx. 1 hakim    phoelex 0 Jan 20 18:41 X26
srwxrwxrwx. 1 bindu    phoelex 0 Mar 16 14:05 X28
srwxrwxrwx. 1 michal   phoelex 0 Nov 18 13:51 X3
srwxrwxrwx. 1 candido  phoelex 0 Feb  2 22:47 X33
srwxrwxrwx. 1 andrew   phoelex 0 Nov 20 13:03 X4
srwxrwxrwx. 1 candido  phoelex 0 Nov 18 14:11 X44
srwxrwxrwx. 1 ed       phoelex 0 Nov 18 13:35 X5
srwxrwxrwx. 1 leighton phoelex 0 Nov 18 13:35 X50
srwxrwxrwx. 1 kathryn  phoelex 0 Nov 18 13:35 X6
srwxrwxrwx. 1 candido  phoelex 0 Nov 18 14:11 X66
srwxrwxrwx. 1 candido  phoelex 0 Nov 18 14:11 X77
srwxrwxrwx. 1 simon    phoelex 0 Dec  2 16:10 X8
srwxrwxrwx. 1 valerio  phoelex 0 Nov 18 13:35 X9
srwxrwxrwx. 1 candido  phoelex 0 Nov 18 14:11 X99

/tmp/.XIM-unix:
total 0
```

Check if there are any Xvnc processes using that display: No

```
(base) [carlos@pulsar ~]$ ps -ef | grep Xvnc
bindu      5815      1  0 14:05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/Xvnc :28 -auth /home/bindu/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:28 (bindu) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/bindu/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5928 -rfbwait 30000
scott      6368      1  0  2020 ?        00:05:09 /usr/bin/Xvnc :13 -auth /home/scott/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:13 (scott) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1024x768 -pn -rfbauth /home/scott/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5913 -rfbwait 30000
stuart    21911      1  0  2020 ?        1-04:07:56 /usr/bin/Xvnc :10 -auth /home/stuart/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:10 (stuart) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/stuart/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5910 -rfbwait 30000
kathryn   22580      1  0  2020 ?        01:28:35 /usr/bin/Xvnc :6 -auth /home/kathryn/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:6 (kathryn) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/kathryn/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5906 -rfbwait 30000
carlos    22581      1  0  2020 ?        11:55:01 /usr/bin/Xvnc :17 -auth /home/carlos/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:17 (carlos) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/carlos/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5917 -rfbwait 30000
ed        22583      1  0  2020 ?        00:05:02 /usr/bin/Xvnc :5 -auth /home/ed/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:5 (ed) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/ed/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5905 -rfbwait 30000
amir      22586      1  0  2020 ?        00:31:29 /usr/bin/Xvnc :1 -auth /home/amir/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:1 (amir) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 3840x2160 -pn -rfbauth /home/amir/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5901 -rfbwait 30000
ranga     22587      1  6  2020 ?        7-11:43:15 /usr/bin/Xvnc :11 -auth /home/ranga/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:11 (ranga) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/ranga/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5911 -rfbwait 30000
zak       22588      1  0  2020 ?        00:05:09 /usr/bin/Xvnc :15 -auth /home/zak/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:15 (zak) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/zak/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5915 -rfbwait 30000
marco     22589      1  0  2020 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/Xvnc :18 -auth /home/marco/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:18 (marco) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/marco/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5918 -rfbwait 30000
valerio   22590      1  0  2020 ?        00:21:37 /usr/bin/Xvnc :9 -auth /home/valerio/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:9 (valerio) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/valerio/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5909 -rfbwait 30000
greg      22591      1  0  2020 ?        01:05:06 /usr/bin/Xvnc :2 -auth /home/greg/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:2 (greg) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 3840x2107 -pn -rfbauth /home/greg/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5902 -rfbwait 30000
leighton  22592      1  0  2020 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/Xvnc :50 -auth /home/leighton/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:50 (leighton) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/leighton/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5950 -rfbwait 30000
michal    22593      1  0  2020 ?        05:05:55 /usr/bin/Xvnc :19 -auth /home/michal/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:19 (michal) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/michal/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5919 -rfbwait 30000
ext-gue+  26418  26214  0  2020 pts/0    00:02:22 /usr/bin/Xvnc :7 -auth /home/ext-guest/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:7 () -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1024x768 -pn -rfbauth /home/ext-guest/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5907 -rfbwait 30000
ext-jiri  26446  26212  0  2020 pts/0    00:04:36 /usr/bin/Xvnc :12 -auth /home/ext-jiri/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:12 () -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1024x768 -pn -rfbauth /home/ext-jiri/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5912 -rfbwait 30000
michal    34129      1  0  2020 ?        00:04:41 /usr/bin/Xvnc :3 -auth /home/michal/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:3 (michal) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1024x768 -pn -rfbauth /home/michal/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5903 -rfbwait 30000
mihai     35252      1  2  2020 ?        3-10:20:08 /usr/bin/Xvnc :25 -auth /home/mihai/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:25 (mihai) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1024x768 -pn -rfbauth /home/mihai/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5925 -rfbwait 30000
candido   38366      1  0  2020 ?        17:13:51 /usr/bin/Xvnc :23 -auth /home/candido/.Xauthority -depth 24 -desktop pulsar:23 (candido) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/candido/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5923 -rfbwait 30000
candido   38417      1  0  2020 ?        06:14:52 /usr/bin/Xvnc :44 -auth /home/candido/.Xauthority -depth 24 -desktop pulsar:44 (candido) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/candido/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5944 -rfbwait 30000
candido   39445      1  0  2020 ?        00:08:03 /usr/bin/Xvnc :66 -auth /home/candido/.Xauthority -depth 24 -desktop pulsar:66 (candido) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/candido/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5966 -rfbwait 30000
candido   40622      1  0  2020 ?        00:05:32 /usr/bin/Xvnc :77 -auth /home/candido/.Xauthority -depth 24 -desktop pulsar:77 (candido) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/candido/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5977 -rfbwait 30000
candido   41288      1  0  2020 ?        04:14:29 /usr/bin/Xvnc :99 -auth /home/candido/.Xauthority -depth 24 -desktop pulsar:99 (candido) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/candido/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5999 -rfbwait 30000
pablo     52358      1  0  2020 ?        04:15:07 /usr/bin/Xvnc :14 -auth /home/pablo/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:14 (pablo) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 3840x2160 -pn -rfbauth /home/pablo/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5914 -rfbwait 30000
andrew    95615      1  0  2020 ?        01:11:49 /usr/bin/Xvnc :4 -auth /home/andrew/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:4 (andrew) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1024x768 -pn -rfbauth /home/andrew/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5904 -rfbwait 30000
candido  177587      1  0 Feb02 ?        00:10:23 /usr/bin/Xvnc :33 -auth /home/candido/.Xauthority -depth 24 -desktop pulsar:33 (candido) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/candido/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5933 -rfbwait 30000
hakim    218843      1  0 Jan20 ?        02:20:58 /usr/bin/Xvnc :26 -auth /home/hakim/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:26 (hakim) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 3840x2160 -pn -rfbauth /home/hakim/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5926 -rfbwait 30000
carlos   222978      1  0 19:17 pts/182  00:00:00 /usr/bin/Xvnc :20 -auth /home/carlos/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:20 (carlos) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1024x768 -pn -rfbauth /home/carlos/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5920 -rfbwait 30000
simon    229121      1  2  2020 ?        2-19:19:09 /usr/bin/Xvnc :8 -auth /home/simon/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:8 (simon) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 3840x2080 -pn -rfbauth /home/simon/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5908 -rfbwait 30000
carlos   237583 126579  0 19:22 pts/182  00:00:00 grep --color=auto Xvnc

(base) [carlos@pulsar .vnc]$ pgrep Xvnc --list-full
5815 /usr/bin/Xvnc :28 -auth /home/bindu/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:28 (bindu) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/bindu/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5928 -rfbwait 30000
6368 /usr/bin/Xvnc :13 -auth /home/scott/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:13 (scott) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1024x768 -pn -rfbauth /home/scott/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5913 -rfbwait 30000
21911 /usr/bin/Xvnc :10 -auth /home/stuart/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:10 (stuart) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/stuart/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5910 -rfbwait 30000
22580 /usr/bin/Xvnc :6 -auth /home/kathryn/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:6 (kathryn) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/kathryn/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5906 -rfbwait 30000
22581 /usr/bin/Xvnc :17 -auth /home/carlos/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:17 (carlos) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/carlos/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5917 -rfbwait 30000
22583 /usr/bin/Xvnc :5 -auth /home/ed/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:5 (ed) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/ed/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5905 -rfbwait 30000
22586 /usr/bin/Xvnc :1 -auth /home/amir/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:1 (amir) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 3840x2160 -pn -rfbauth /home/amir/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5901 -rfbwait 30000
22587 /usr/bin/Xvnc :11 -auth /home/ranga/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:11 (ranga) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/ranga/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5911 -rfbwait 30000
22588 /usr/bin/Xvnc :15 -auth /home/zak/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:15 (zak) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/zak/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5915 -rfbwait 30000
22589 /usr/bin/Xvnc :18 -auth /home/marco/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:18 (marco) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/marco/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5918 -rfbwait 30000
22590 /usr/bin/Xvnc :9 -auth /home/valerio/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:9 (valerio) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/valerio/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5909 -rfbwait 30000
22591 /usr/bin/Xvnc :2 -auth /home/greg/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:2 (greg) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 3840x2107 -pn -rfbauth /home/greg/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5902 -rfbwait 30000
22592 /usr/bin/Xvnc :50 -auth /home/leighton/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:50 (leighton) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/leighton/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5950 -rfbwait 30000
22593 /usr/bin/Xvnc :19 -auth /home/michal/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:19 (michal) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/michal/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5919 -rfbwait 30000
26418 /usr/bin/Xvnc :7 -auth /home/ext-guest/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:7 () -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1024x768 -pn -rfbauth /home/ext-guest/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5907 -rfbwait 30000
26446 /usr/bin/Xvnc :12 -auth /home/ext-jiri/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:12 () -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1024x768 -pn -rfbauth /home/ext-jiri/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5912 -rfbwait 30000
34129 /usr/bin/Xvnc :3 -auth /home/michal/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:3 (michal) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1024x768 -pn -rfbauth /home/michal/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5903 -rfbwait 30000
35252 /usr/bin/Xvnc :25 -auth /home/mihai/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:25 (mihai) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1024x768 -pn -rfbauth /home/mihai/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5925 -rfbwait 30000
38366 /usr/bin/Xvnc :23 -auth /home/candido/.Xauthority -depth 24 -desktop pulsar:23 (candido) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/candido/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5923 -rfbwait 30000
38417 /usr/bin/Xvnc :44 -auth /home/candido/.Xauthority -depth 24 -desktop pulsar:44 (candido) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/candido/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5944 -rfbwait 30000
39445 /usr/bin/Xvnc :66 -auth /home/candido/.Xauthority -depth 24 -desktop pulsar:66 (candido) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/candido/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5966 -rfbwait 30000
40622 /usr/bin/Xvnc :77 -auth /home/candido/.Xauthority -depth 24 -desktop pulsar:77 (candido) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/candido/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5977 -rfbwait 30000
41288 /usr/bin/Xvnc :99 -auth /home/candido/.Xauthority -depth 24 -desktop pulsar:99 (candido) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/candido/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5999 -rfbwait 30000
52358 /usr/bin/Xvnc :14 -auth /home/pablo/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:14 (pablo) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 3840x2160 -pn -rfbauth /home/pablo/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5914 -rfbwait 30000
95615 /usr/bin/Xvnc :4 -auth /home/andrew/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:4 (andrew) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1024x768 -pn -rfbauth /home/andrew/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5904 -rfbwait 30000
115649 /usr/bin/Xvnc :21 -auth /home/humberto/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:21 (humberto) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/humberto/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5921 -rfbwait 30000
177587 /usr/bin/Xvnc :33 -auth /home/candido/.Xauthority -depth 24 -desktop pulsar:33 (candido) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1920x1080 -pn -rfbauth /home/candido/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5933 -rfbwait 30000
218843 /usr/bin/Xvnc :26 -auth /home/hakim/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:26 (hakim) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 3840x2160 -pn -rfbauth /home/hakim/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5926 -rfbwait 30000
222978 /usr/bin/Xvnc :20 -auth /home/carlos/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:20 (carlos) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 1024x768 -pn -rfbauth /home/carlos/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5920 -rfbwait 30000
229121 /usr/bin/Xvnc :8 -auth /home/simon/.Xauthority -desktop pulsar:8 (simon) -fp catalogue:/etc/X11/fontpath.d -geometry 3840x2080 -pn -rfbauth /home/simon/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5908 -rfbwait 30000
```

Check if there are any processes listening on the corresponding ports: No

```
(base) [carlos@pulsar ~]$ sudo netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':5916'
(base) [carlos@pulsar ~]$ sudo netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':6016'
```

For comparison, this is for a working VNC session:

```
(base) [carlos@pulsar ~]$ sudo netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':5917'
tcp6       0      0 :::5917                 :::*                    LISTEN      22581/Xvnc          
(base) [carlos@pulsar ~]$ sudo netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':6017'
tcp6       0      0 :::6017                 :::*                    LISTEN      22581/Xvnc
```

Check that the port is open: Yes

```
(base) [carlos@pulsar ~]$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=5916/tcp
Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: 5916:tcp
success
(base) [carlos@pulsar ~]$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
success
```

So I tried to telnet from the server itself:

```
(base) [carlos@pulsar .vnc]$ telnet localhost 5916
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

In the case of a working session I can connect:

```
(base) [carlos@pulsar .vnc]$ telnet localhost 5917
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
RFB 003.008
^CConnection closed by foreign host.
```

When scanning the ports from a different machine in the same LAN:

```
(base) [carlos@blazar ~]$ nmap pulsar.phoelex.com -Pn -p 5916

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2021-03-16 19:32 GMT
Nmap scan report for pulsar.phoelex.com (192.168.1.33)
Host is up (0.00028s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5916/tcp closed unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.04 seconds
(base) [carlos@blazar ~]$ nmap pulsar.phoelex.com -Pn -p 5917

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2021-03-16 19:33 GMT
Nmap scan report for pulsar.phoelex.com (192.168.1.33)
Host is up (0.00035s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
5917/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.04 seconds
```

Looking at the IP tables, IN_public_allow/deny section:

```
(base) [carlos@pulsar .vnc]$ sudo iptables -L -n

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5901 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5902 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5915 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5913 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5917 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5916 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5908 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5914 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5009 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5909 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5921 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5920 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5922 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5904 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5905 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5906 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5950 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5918 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5919 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5910 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5911 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:111 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:111 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:2049 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:24007 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:24008 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5907 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5923 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5924 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5925 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5903 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5926 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5928 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5912 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5927 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

At this point I'm out of ideas what could be causing this, and starting to worry that it might be something malicious. Any further steps to debug this issue would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a solution, but we had to reboot the server for unrelated reasons, and the problem has dissapeared.